# Preprocess problem Faster RCNN in tensorflow object detection API

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I've wrapped meta-architecture with the code below:

```
num_classes = 1
model_conf = 'models/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config'
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(model_conf)
model_config = configs['model']
model_config.faster_rcnn.num_classes = num_classes
model_config.faster_rcnn.feature_extractor.batch_norm_trainable = False
model_config.faster_rcnn.number_of_stages = 2
model_config.faster_rcnn.second_stage_post_processing.batch_non_max_suppression.max_detections_per_class=150



class MyDetectionModel(tf.keras.Model): # ADAPTER
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(MyDetectionModel, self).__init__()
        self.detection_model = model
        #self.detection_model.build(x,y,z)
        #image, shapes = self.detection_model.preprocess(tf.concat([tf.zeros([1, 640, 640, 3]),tf.zeros([1, 640, 640, 3]) ],axis=0))
        #prediction_dict = self.detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
        #_ = self.detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
        
    def select_variable_to_fine_tune(self):
        # TO-DO
        return None

    def print_training_variable(self):
        print(list(self.to_fine_tune))

    def train_step(self, data):
        image_tensors, gt = data[0], data[1]
        groundtruth_boxes_list,groundtruth_classes_list = gt[0], gt[1]
        shapes = tf.constant(len(image_tensors) * [[640, 640, 3]], dtype=tf.int32) # risolve il problema della dimensione del batch
        # GROUDTRUTH
        self.detection_model.provide_groundtruth(
            groundtruth_boxes_list=groundtruth_boxes_list, 
            groundtruth_classes_list=groundtruth_classes_list,)

        ### debug
        #print(image_tensors[0][0])

        ###
          
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            preprocessed_images = tf.concat([self.detection_model.preprocess(image_tensor)[0] for image_tensor in image_tensors], axis=0)
            #print(preprocessed_images)
            prediction_dict = self.detection_model.predict(preprocessed_images, shapes) # differenza con i model tradizionali: qui uso predict e richiede shape
            losses_dict = self.detection_model.loss(prediction_dict, shapes)
            total_loss = losses_dict['Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss'] + losses_dict['Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss'] + losses_dict['Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss'] + losses_dict['Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss']
        gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.detection_model.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.detection_model.trainable_variables))
        tl = total_loss
        return{
            "total_loss": tl ,
            "Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss":losses_dict['Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss'] ,
            "Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss":losses_dict['Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss'],
            "Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss":losses_dict['Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss'],
            "Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss":losses_dict['Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss']
        }
    
    def test_step(self, data):
        ### TO DO
        
        return None
```

and I train it with the following code:

```
my_model = MyDetectionModel(detection_model)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)
my_model.compile(optimizer)
my_model.fit(
    x = train_image_tensors,
    y = (gt_box_tensors,gt_classes_one_hot_tensors),
    epochs = 150,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    #verbose = 1,
    )
```

The training goes well, with the losses that go down, but at test stage the preprocess function give the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-9b4b502bec7a> in <module>()
     34   a = np.resize(test_images_np[i],(1,1000,1000,3))
     35   input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
---> 36   detections = detect(input_tensor)
     37   #print(detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.uint32)+label_id_offset, detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy() )
     38   print(detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy() )

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-50-08bee00ed330>:25 detect  *
        prediction_dict = my_model.detection_model.predict(preprocessed_image, shapes)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:818 predict  *
        prediction_dict.update(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:991 _predict_second_stage  *
        proposal_boxes_normalized, num_proposals = self._proposal_postprocess(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:721 _proposal_postprocess  *
        proposal_boxes_normalized, _, _, num_proposals, _, _ =         self._postprocess_rpn(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:1694 _postprocess_rpn  *
        (groundtruth_boxlists, groundtruth_classes_with_background_list, _,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:1829 _format_groundtruth_data  *
        groundtruth_boxlists = [
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1024 _slice_helper
        name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1196 strided_slice
        shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:10352 strided_slice
        shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:744 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:593 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3485 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1975 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1815 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice_11}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=3](Tile, strided_slice_11/stack, strided_slice_11/stack_1, strided_slice_11/stack_2)' with input shapes: [1,3], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 0>, input[2] = <2 1>, input[3] = <1 1>.
```

the code used for predeticting is:

```
test_image_dir = 'models/research/object_detection/test_images/ducky/test/'
test_images_np = []
for i in range(1, 50):
  image_path = os.path.join(test_image_dir, 'out' + str(i) + '.jpg')
  test_images_np.append(np.expand_dims(
      load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path), axis=0))

@tf.function
def detect(input_tensor):
  """Run detection on an input image.

  Args:
    input_tensor: A [1, height, width, 3] Tensor of type tf.float32.
      Note that height and width can be anything since the image will be
      immediately resized according to the needs of the model within this
      function.

  Returns:
    A dict containing 3 Tensors (`detection_boxes`, `detection_classes`,
      and `detection_scores`).
  """
  preprocessed_image, shapes = my_model.detection_model.preprocess(input_tensor)
  prediction_dict = my_model.detection_model.predict(preprocessed_image, shapes)
  return my_model.detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)

# Note that the first frame will trigger tracing of the tf.function, which will
# take some time, after which inference should be fast.

label_id_offset = 1
for i in range(len(test_images_np)):
  print(i)
  a = np.resize(test_images_np[i],(1,1000,1000,3))
  input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
  detections = detect(input_tensor)
  #print(detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.uint32)+label_id_offset, detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy() )
  print(detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy() )
  plot_detections(
      test_images_np[i][0],
      detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
      detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.uint32)
      + label_id_offset,
      detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
      category_index, figsize=(15, 20),image_name="gif_frame_" + ('%02d' % i) + ".jpg")
```

The strange thing is that the same function that give me an error at prediction stage, works properly in `train_step` method.

Removing the tf.function annotation the error became:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f3417ad28e97> in <module>()
     33   a = np.resize(test_images_np[i],(1,1000,1000,3))
     34   input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
---> 35   detections = detect(input_tensor)
     36   #print(detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.uint32)+label_id_offset, detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy() )
     37   print(detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy() )

17 frames
<ipython-input-23-f3417ad28e97> in detect(input_tensor)
     22   """
     23   preprocessed_image, shapes = my_model.detection_model.preprocess(input_tensor)
---> 24   prediction_dict = my_model.detection_model.predict(preprocessed_image, shapes)
     25   return my_model.detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
     26 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py in predict(self, preprocessed_inputs, true_image_shapes, **side_inputs)
    822               prediction_dict['rpn_features_to_crop'],
    823               prediction_dict['anchors'], prediction_dict['image_shape'],
--> 824               true_image_shapes, **side_inputs))
    825 
    826     if self._number_of_stages == 3:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py in _predict_second_stage(self, rpn_box_encodings, rpn_objectness_predictions_with_background, rpn_features_to_crop, anchors, image_shape, true_image_shapes, **side_inputs)
    991     proposal_boxes_normalized, num_proposals = self._proposal_postprocess(
    992         rpn_box_encodings, rpn_objectness_predictions_with_background, anchors,
--> 993         image_shape, true_image_shapes)
    994     prediction_dict = self._box_prediction(rpn_features_to_crop,
    995                                            proposal_boxes_normalized,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py in _proposal_postprocess(self, rpn_box_encodings, rpn_objectness_predictions_with_background, anchors, image_shape, true_image_shapes)
    722         self._postprocess_rpn(
    723             rpn_box_encodings, rpn_objectness_predictions_with_background,
--> 724             anchors, image_shape_2d, true_image_shapes)
    725     return proposal_boxes_normalized, num_proposals
    726 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py in _postprocess_rpn(self, rpn_box_encodings_batch, rpn_objectness_predictions_with_background_batch, anchors, image_shapes, true_image_shapes)
   1694         (groundtruth_boxlists, groundtruth_classes_with_background_list, _,
   1695          groundtruth_weights_list
-> 1696         ) = self._format_groundtruth_data(image_shapes)
   1697         (proposal_boxes, proposal_scores,
   1698          num_proposals) = self._sample_box_classifier_batch(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py in _format_groundtruth_data(self, image_shapes)
   1831             box_list.BoxList(boxes), image_shapes[i, 0], image_shapes[i, 1])
   1832         for i, boxes in enumerate(
-> 1833             self.groundtruth_lists(fields.BoxListFields.boxes))
   1834     ]
   1835     groundtruth_classes_with_background_list = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1830         box_list_ops.to_absolute_coordinates(
   1831             box_list.BoxList(boxes), image_shapes[i, 0], image_shapes[i, 1])
-> 1832         for i, boxes in enumerate(
   1833             self.groundtruth_lists(fields.BoxListFields.boxes))
   1834     ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/core/box_list_ops.py in to_absolute_coordinates(boxlist, height, width, check_range, maximum_normalized_coordinate, scope)
    910     # Ensure range of input boxes is correct.
    911     if check_range:
--> 912       box_maximum = tf.reduce_max(boxlist.get())
    913       max_assert = tf.Assert(
    914           tf.greater_equal(maximum_normalized_coordinate, box_maximum),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in reduce_max_v1(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name, reduction_indices, keep_dims)
   2636   keepdims = deprecation.deprecated_argument_lookup("keepdims", keepdims,
   2637                                                     "keep_dims", keep_dims)
-> 2638   return reduce_max(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name)
   2639 
   2640 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in reduce_max(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name)
   2684   """
   2685   return reduce_max_with_dims(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name,
-> 2686                               _ReductionDims(input_tensor, axis))
   2687 
   2688 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in reduce_max_with_dims(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name, dims)
   2695   return _may_reduce_to_scalar(
   2696       keepdims, axis,
-> 2697       gen_math_ops._max(input_tensor, dims, keepdims, name=name))
   2698 
   2699 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in _max(input, axis, keep_dims, name)
   5710     try:
   5711       return _max_eager_fallback(
-> 5712           input, axis, keep_dims=keep_dims, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
   5713     except _core._SymbolicException:
   5714       pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in _max_eager_fallback(input, axis, keep_dims, name, ctx)
   5742   _attrs = ("keep_dims", keep_dims, "T", _attr_T, "Tidx", _attr_Tidx)
   5743   _result = _execute.execute(b"Max", 1, inputs=_inputs_flat, attrs=_attrs,
-> 5744                              ctx=ctx, name=name)
   5745   if _execute.must_record_gradient():
   5746     _execute.record_gradient(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     73           "Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic "
     74           "tensors, but found {}".format(keras_symbolic_tensors))
---> 75     raise e
     76   # pylint: enable=protected-access
     77   return tensors

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: IteratorGetNext:5
```
````